# PNP output low voltage is not 0V

Tags: transistors

[image]
First, I'm a new bee to electronics.

With the above circuit, why the output is 0.6V instead of 0V?

I wanna achieve input HIGH at base and output HIGH, input LOW with output LOW. but the LOW voltage is not 0V.

Where is the problem and how I edit it?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Looks like someone needs to learn much more about transistors.

Comment: Others explained why this is expected. If you want to fix it, the easiest thing is to just use a logic buffer instead of a transistor.

Answer (score 1):

For a PNP emitter follower, like your circuit, the emitter will always be about 0.6 - 0.7 volts more positive than the base.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the transistor needs a voltage of about 0.6V between the base and the emitter, VBE, in order to turn on or be in the active region. What you have is completely normal and expected. The transistor needs to consume some energy in order to turn on. To solve this problem you could use a level shifter, which is usually another transistor (maybe NPN) which will consume the 0.6V at the output and having its own output at 0V. (I'm not an expert on level shifters)

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, what you have is normal and expected.

Also, "LOW" doesn't means 0V, the devices which you are willing to use will have their own specifications on "Below what voltage to consider something LOW" and "Above what voltage to consider something HIGH". Usual used logics now days consider more than 3.3 or 3.7V as high and less than 1.5 or 1.7 as low, but these levels varies with various devices and logic families they belong to. You can find specifications in datasheet, but as far as I've played, 0.6V is enough low to be taken as "LOW", by most of things...